# in real analysis how to show there exist a continuous function $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

How to show there exists a continuous function $f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1 \dfrac{f(t)}{(\pi+(x-t)^4)}dt = f(x)- \pi x$$ $\text{for all } x \in [-1,1]$

Comment: What have you tried? Show your own efforts to get answer(s).

Answer (score 1):

Let $T:C[-1,1] \to C[-1,1]$ be defined by

$$(Tf)(x)=\int_{-1}^1 \dfrac{f(t)}{\pi+(x-t)^4}dt + \pi x.$$

Furthermore $C[-1,1]$ is with the $|| \cdot||_{\infty}$ - norm a Banach space. Now show that for $f,g \in C[-1,1]$ and $x \in [-1,1]$ we have

$$ |(Tf)(x)-(Tg)(x)| \le \frac{2}{\pi}||f-g||_{\infty}.$$

Hence

$$||Tf-Tg||_{\infty} \le \frac{2}{\pi}||f-g||_{\infty}.$$

Now Banach's contraction principle shows that there is a unique function $f \in C[-1,1]$ such that

$$Tf=f.$$

Comment: One still needs to show that $T$ is well-defined.